# How to stop play sound if silent mode is turned on

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

My code:

```
NSString *soundName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundName];
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
self.backgroundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];

if (self.backgroundPlayer == nil) {
    NSLog(@"error = %@",[error description]);
} else {
    [self.backgroundPlayer setDelegate:self];
    [self.backgroundPlayer setNumberOfLoops:HUGE_VAL];
    [self.backgroundPlayer setVolume:0.5f];
    [self.backgroundPlayer prepareToPlay];
    if ([self.backgroundPlayer prepareToPlay]) {
        if ([self.backgroundPlayer play]) {
            NSLog(@"playing");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error!");
    }
}
```

When I switch iPhone to silent mode sound still plays. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to user AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient for audio session. go though [audio session programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Basics/Basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH2-SW2).

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tried this, but you can set the audio category before playing the file:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CFStringRef state;

UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);

AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);
if(CFStringGetLength(state) == 0)
{
//SI

    else
    {
    //NOT SILENT

    }
```

you can detect the state of phone and stop your player .. :)